# Iteratively edit a single file

Tags: text-processing

I have a single file with a statement that looks like this :

```
myName_tx_1 VARCHAR(255)
myName_in_1 VARCHAR(255)
myName_tx_2 VARCHAR(255)
myName_in_2 VARCHAR(255)
myName_tx_3 VARCHAR(255)
myName_in_3 VARCHAR(255)
myAddress_tx_1 VARCHAR(255)
myAddress_in_2 VARCHAR(255)
etc
```

I would like to change this to :

```
myName_tx_1 VARCHAR(255)
myName_in_1 VARCHAR(1)
myName_tx_2 VARCHAR(255)
myName_in_2 VARCHAR(1)
myName_tx_3 VARCHAR(255)
myName_in_3 VARCHAR(1)
myAddress_tx_1 VARCHAR(255)
myAddress_in_2 VARCHAR(1)
etc
```

Anyway, the further qualification to the problem is that I only want to change the entries where the name of the attribute ends in 'in$' where $ is a number (like myName_in_3 VARCHAR(255), as an example).

As it happens, the '_in' (Indicator attributes) come in pairs, so doing the n~2 (or FNR%2==0) is quite smart, but I do wonder if it's better to identify the '_in$ VARCHAR(255)' as the pattern for change.

How would I do this using easily understandable code ?  The file is not big, so performance is not the main issue .... just trying to avoid a lot of manual vi editing.

Comment: Could you clarify what you need to change? It looks like you want every second 255 to become a 1. Is that correct? Will the values always be 255?

Answer (score 6):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR%2==0{sub(255,1)}1' file
myName_tx_1 VARCHAR(255)
myName_in_1 VARCHAR(1)
myName_tx_2 VARCHAR(255)
myName_in_2 VARCHAR(1)
myName_tx_3 VARCHAR(255)
myName_in_3 VARCHAR(1)
myAddress_tx_1 VARCHAR(255)
myAddress_in_2 VARCHAR(1)
```

**Explanation**

- `FNR%2==0` only matches even lines.
- If line is even, we replace `255` with `1`, `sub(255,1)`.
- `1` is a true condition, make `awk` print `$0`.

The same logic can be used with other tools, like `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/255/1/ unless $. % 2' file
```

With `sed`, you can do:

```
sed -e 'n;s/255/1/' file
```

**Update**

With your update requirement, we can change solution a little.

With `awk`:

```
awk '/_in_[0-9]/{sub(255,1)}1' file
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -e '/_in_[0-9]/{s/255/1/}' file
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/255/1/ if /_in_[0-9]/' file
```

Comment: +1 for `awk`. That is the perfect tool for this task.

Comment: sure was the same. my bad. and @HalosGhost - obviously the perfect tool was `sed` - *iterative edits* are what it was born to do - it is *the* stream editor. you don't need the `-e` though.. but - why answer a question you don't find worthwhile? and if you do - why not upvote it?

Comment: @mikeserv, I'm confused; I didn't answer this question…

Comment: @HalosGhost - oh, I know. Sorry about that. I only meant to *(in a playfully competitive sense)* address you regarding `sed` v `awk`. The rest was for Gnouc because I stupidly repeated his `sed` answer in a since deleted one of my own.

Comment: @mikeserv, ahh, fair enough. As much as I love `sed`, this task seems like it's what `awk` was designed for.

Comment: @HalosGhost - *seriously*? `sed 'n;s/255/1/'` - *replace the first occurring `255` string with the string `1` on every other line starting with the second* - you think `awk` was designed to do that? Based on what I read, `awk` was designed to do much more complex editing that - specifically mathematical functions based on field-separated data read in line by line.

Answer (score 6):

With GNU sed you can specify line addresses in `first~step` format so to modify every other line starting with the second you could use address `2~2` e.g.

```
$ sed '2~2 s/(255)/(1)/' file
myName_tx_1 VARCHAR(255)
myName_in_1 VARCHAR(1)
myName_tx_2 VARCHAR(255)
myName_in_2 VARCHAR(1)
myName_tx_3 VARCHAR(255)
myName_in_3 VARCHAR(1)
myAddress_tx_1 VARCHAR(255)
myAddress_in_2 VARCHAR(1)
```

Comment: Nice! Learn something new about `sed` everyday.

Comment: @HalosGhost I can't say I've ever used it IRL!

Answer (score 3):

There's

```
sed '/_in_/ s/255/1/'
```

which means: for lines matching `/_in_/`, search for `255` and replace with `1`.

Answer (score -1):

```
cat oldfile.txt |awk '/_in_[0-9]/{sub(255,1)}1' > newfile.txt
```